# error in rawquery :near ","

Tags: android, sqlite

while trying to insert data i am getting this error

```
07-29 18:15:19.909: E/sqlite(863): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO transactions (details , amount) VALUES( , );
```

i think the error is in this line unable to sort it help anyone

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO " +stdb.tname+" (" + stdb.details+" , "+stdb.amt+") VALUES("+setdet+" , "+setamt+");";
```

Comment: It appears `setdet` and `setamt` don't have any valid data as the error is showing `VALUES( , )`

Comment: Also, query-strings should not be `;`-terminated **and** your application is susceptible for [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @LukasKnuth sir how it should be sorry for poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `setdet` and `setamt` are empty. which results in the invalid statement:

```
INSERT INTO transactions (details , amount) VALUES( , );
```

Comment: thanks sir i was to post other error that i was getting i made an mistake sorry for the inconvenience the error i was getting is no such table

Comment: So is it answered/close question?